# Detecting an action performed to an instance in xform

Tags: xforms

I would like to know how to detect if a user has made a change to any input field in a form. The reason for this is to enable a checkbox to save changes to a database.
I would like to avoid writing triggers for each field. Is there a general why this can be done to the model instance, where it compares the instance loaded to the one updated by the user?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a group element for all the input controls in your form then xforms-value-changed event can be captured by it because of the bubbling mechanism.

-Alain